# String comparison in awk

Tags: string, awk, syntax

I need to compare two strings in alphabetic order, not only equality test.  I want to know is there way to do string comparison in awk?

Comment: Of course you can - it's primarily a string-processing language.

Comment: This is a misconception. For instance the expression `$1 == $2` will falsely report that the strings `001` and `1.0` are equal.

Answer (score 35):

Sure it can:

```
pax$ echo 'hello
goodbye' | gawk '{if ($0 == "hello") {print "HELLO"}}'
HELLO
```

You can also do *inequality* (ordered) testing as well:

```
pax> printf 'aaa\naab\naac\naad\n' | gawk '{if ($1 < "aac"){print}}'
aaa
aab
```

Comment: The operator < will only compare first letter per my experience. Hence it will not compare strings. You have to use != operator.

Comment: @Sumod, then your implementation of `awk` is broken. In any case `!=` is useless for ordering strings as per the question. See the update for string comparison beyond the first character, and I'd suggest switching to using the GNU variant.

Comment: OK. I am using awk that comes with CentOS 6.4. It says GNU awk 3.1.7. Please see the input of my commands. <br/>$jps - 29420 Jps, 28009 RunJar, 27501 DseDaemon. If I give the command - jps | awk '{if ($2 < "Jps") {print $2}}', then only DseDaemon is printed. If I use "!=", then both RunJar and DseDaemon are printed. Hence I reached this conclusion. Please excuse typos. Not able to copy paste exact commands.

Comment: @Sumod, if your three lines are `29420 Jps`, `28009 RunJar` and `27501 DseDemon`, then it's acting correctly. The `DseDemon` string is the **only** one less than `Jps`. `RunJar` is greater and `Jps` is **equal** so neither of those will print. Try another line containing `11111 Jpr` and see what happens, I think you'll find it prints out fine. If you want to include the `Jps` line in your output, you should be using `<=` rather than `<`.

Comment: Beware that `awk` has no explicit typing and tries to convert everything to numbers first, which sometime lead to "interesting" results:

```
awk -v a=0200 -v b=02E2 'BEGIN{print(a==b)}'
```

Instead of string comparison you get comparison by numbers, e.g. "02E2" is scientific notation for 02*10²=200 and you get True.
You can force string comparison by prefixing some string, which is guaranteed to not be numeric, e.g.

```
awk -v a=0200 -v b=02E2 'BEGIN{print(("x" a)==("x" b))}'
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do string comparison in awk using standard boolean operators, unlike in C where you would have to use strcmp().

`echo "xxx yyy" > test.txt`

`cat test.txt | awk '$1!=$2 { print($1 $2); }'`

Comment: Don't use cat here, awk is perfectly capable of reading a file by it self. Useless Use of Cat Award springs to mind... http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: Well, you are right. It might be as follows: `awk '...' test.txt`. Thanks for the link.

Comment: "Useless Use of Cat Award" is great to have in you toolbox :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can check the answer in the [nawk manual](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_61.html)

```
echo aaa bbb | awk '{ print ($1 >= $2) ? "true" : "false" }'
```